# How do i get TypeScript source files to show up in node inspector?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, node-inspector

I'm working a node express app using typescript 2.3.

I compile using tsc

I would like to be able to debug my TypeScript code using node-inspector (now bundled with node 6.3+)

I have sourceMaps turned on in my tsConfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noResolve": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I also see the following when connected through the WebUI for fish.controller.js

```
exports.FishController = FishController;
//# sourceMappingURL=fish.controller.js.map
});
```

The problem is that i do NOT see the actual TypeScript source or map files in the node-inspector window.

I've ensured they exist:

```
$ ls -l

-rw-r--r--  1 xxx  staff    945 Sep 19 14:32 fish.controller.d.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 xxx  staff   5318 Sep 19 14:32 fish.controller.js
-rw-r--r--  1 xxx  staff   8528 Sep 19 14:32 fish.controller.js.map
```

How do i include the TS Files and set breakpoints? [image]

Comment: You can read on how sourcemaps work for debugging here: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/debugging-node-js-projects-with-typescript-and-vs-code-digging-into-sourcemaps

Comment: Not directly related, but i was able to get the webstorm debugger to work by configuring a Chromium Remote session, and then providing a "mapRoot": "dist/" option in tsconfig.json

Answer (score -2):

Can you try to set `sourceMap: false` and instead add

`"inlineSources": true,
 "inlineSourceMap": true`

to your `compilerOptions` of tsconfig.json?

This will add your sources and sourceMap to the compiled JS files. The Chrome inspector should be able to extract the sources.